# Цикл для массива кнопок

Tags: c#

Суть в том, что есть 9 кнопок. Если нажать на одну из этих кнопок на этой кнопке должен появиться текст "Х". Как это сделать через цикл, а не вручную ?

Вот пример, как это выглядит для одной кнопки

```
var button1 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
        button1.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
            button1.Text = "X";
        };
```

кнопки называются так : button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6, button7, button8, button9

Comment: Winforms? WPF? Asp.NET?

Comment: xamarin..... :D

Comment: не попал :) Вам надо только 1 обработчик написать,типа `void buttonHandler(object sender, EventArgs e) => (sender as Button).Text = "X";` и потом на все кнопки его навесить, типа `new List<Button>(){button1, button2, ....}.ForEach(b=>b.Click +=buttonHandler)`

Comment: {button1, button2,  и т.д подчеркивает красным, пишет, мол, the name does not exist in the current context

Comment: нужно для всех 9-ти кнопок записать так ...... ?? var button1 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);

Comment: грубо говоря найти по ID все 9 кнопок ?

Comment: да, найти их все по id или есть есть возможность, перечислить все кнопки поиском (хз есть такое в Xamarin или нет)

Comment: а можно их как-то в массив обернуть ?

Comment: чтобы все эти кнопки хранились в массиве

Comment: типа `var buttons = new []{Resource.Id.button1, Resource.Id.button2, ...., Resource.Id.button9}.Select(b=>FindViewById<Button>(b)).ToList();` ? И потом `buttons.ForEach(b=>b.Click +=buttonHandler)`

Comment: дааа, то, что нужно !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам надо только 1 обработчик написать

```
void buttonHandler(object sender, EventArgs e) => (sender as Button).Text = "X";
```

и потом на все кнопки его навесить

```
var buttons = new []{Resource.Id.button1, Resource.Id.button2, ...., Resource.Id.button9}
           .Select(b=>FindViewById<Button>(b)).ToList();
buttons.ForEach(b=>b.Click +=buttonHandler);
```